# Which tag should we use? [anime-physics] vs. [physics]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

"Anime Physics" is the commonly accepted term for anything dealing with the physics or mechanics in the Anime/Manga universe.

**Option 1:** [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics)

1. It is the standard and most commonly recognized term.
2. The "anime" part seems redundant since this **is** an Anime and Manga site.
3. The "anime" part seems to implicitly exclude Manga despite the term being mostly universal.

**Option 2:** [physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics)

1. It removes the redundancy of "anime" since it is already implied.
2. It confuses "Anime Physics" with actual *real* physics.
3. It applies equally to both Anime and Manga.

What we don't want is two tags: [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) and [manga-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-physics)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vote this up for **Option 1:** [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics)

Comment: I cast my own vote for option 1.

Comment: I think it is not redundant. "Anime physics" is a quite commonly used term used to denote (somewhat sarcastically) the physics laws in the fictional anime world. It can apply to both anime and manga.

Comment: [tag:anime-physics] it is.

Answer (score 1):

Vote this up for **Option 2:** [physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics)