# Can we have a Physics tag in Anime SE?

Tags: discussion

In Science Fiction SE, they have a Physics tag so you can ask something related to Physics in the context of a science fiction. I imagine that if I open such a question in Anime SE without a Physics tag, someone is going to say that's a question for Physics SE, where it would likely get closed. The alternative is to post it in the Science Fiction SE under the Physics and Anime tags, but it would be a shame to lose some of those questions to another SE in my opinion.

Can we have a Physics tag in Anime SE?

Comment: Related: [Anime-physics vs Physics](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366/which-tag-should-we-use-anime-physics-vs-physics/367#367) & [are anime physics a good fit?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/are-anime-physics-questions-a-good-fit-for-our-site) & [Should we keep the anime-physics tag](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-anime-physics-a-tag-we-should-keep)